# IOS + Add Event in Device calender with EKRecurrenceRule

Tags: ios, ekeventkit

I want to add event in device calendar on monthly which is working fine to me. But the problem is occurred in second condition. Suppose we add one event on 31st of each month and if 31 is not exist in that month then add on last day of that month such 30 April, 28 Feb.

Any suggestion to solve that condition???

Thanks

Comment: do you know exactly what the user is trying to do? If I am adding an event on the 31st of Jan, does that mean I want a recurring event on all 31sts during the year or does it mean that I want to add an recurring event on the last day of the month?